# Cordova 2.1.0 creating new db in /app_database/file__0 + android app development

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I'm using Cordova 2.1.0 for android app development and I am creating db tables in the following location through java android:

> /data/data/com.ingenyous.alerts.android/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db

And then, on `window.openDatabase()`, Cordova (version 2.1.0), by default, is creating another file `0000000000000002.db` in the same location.

Why is it creating new file instead of using the tables created in `0000000000000001.db`?

With Phonegap 1.3, I did not face this problem as it was using the already existing db.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: since there's a new version, it could be dead bug